# Spring Schwduler without @Scheduled annotation/xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled

Is there any way to schedule a task in using spring scheduler without using @Scheduled  annotation /xml Configuration..

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html

Comment: @bmarkham..thank you..